# Selecting options from all drop downs on a product from a result list

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am trying to learn about Watir, so please bear with me. I have a product on a website that has multiple drop down options (size, color, config), and I need to loop through a block of code until every drop down has an option selected so that I can add to item to my cart.

The first drop down box is clicked and the option is selected successfully. The second drop down box is clicked, but I am getting an error saying that the element (option) is unable to be found, even though each drop down uses the same HTML. Can someone help me figure out how to get the additional drop down options to be selected?

Here is my ruby code:

```
skuString = @browser.button(:text, 'Add To Cart').id
sku = skuString[/[^_]+/]
skuOptions = hapi.getProduct(sku)
numOfOptions = skuOptions['products'][0]['options'].size

numOfOptions.times do |n|
@browser.spans(:class, 'HN-Item-Opt-Ar bg-hn-background icon-down-open')[n].when_present.click

if @browser.div(:class, 'standard-style HN-Item-Opt relativePosition ng-scope').exists?
   @browser.div(:class, 'standard-style HN-Item-Opt relativePosition ng-scope').when_present.click
else @browser.div(:class, 'standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope').when_present.click
end
end
```

And here is the error I receive on the second drop down:

```
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 90 seconds, waiting for {:class=>"standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope", :tag_name=>"div"} to become present
./features/step_definitions/result_lists.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/result_lists.rb:32:in `times'
./features/step_definitions/result_lists.rb:32:in `/^I select options in the modal$/'
```

Here is the HTML of the options section:

```
<div class="paddingSides15px paddingTopOnly5px borderTop border-hn-secondary-lt">

    <div hn-product-options="" options="model.product.options" variation="model.product.variation" productid="model.product.productID" class="ng-scope">

            <div hn-product-option="" ng-class="{'option-invalid': !option.valueSelected}" option="options[0]" class="ng-scope option-invalid">
                <div hn-select="" label="Bed Size (2)" select-name=" - Bed Size" on-collapse="getValueData(args)" class="marginTopOnly10px hn-option ng-isolate-scope" hn-input-disable="" hn-input-disable-exclude="lastSelectedOption == option" enable-on="hnProductOptions:updateComplete" disable-on="hnProductOptions:updating" content-width="654"><div class="HN-Select-Option">
<div ng-click="toggleContent()" style="height:100%;overflow: hidden;" class="">
    <div class="standard-style text-small noWrap">
        <div class="HN-Opt-Lbl noWrap inline-block ng-binding" hn-bind-html="displayData">Bed Size (2)</div>
        <div swatch-preview="" class="inline-block swatch-preview-cont ng-scope" style="width: 0px;">
            <!-- ngRepeat: img in swatches.images -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="HN-Item-Opt-Ar bg-hn-background icon-down-open"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-error text-small ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="hasCustomErrorCondition ? errorCondition() : (data.isCustomKitOption ? (dirty &amp;&amp; !data.valid &amp;&amp; !data.isPristine) : displayError)">
    Please Select<br>
    Your  - Bed Size
</div>
<div ng-transclude="" class="hn-select-content" ng-class="{'open-to-left':openToLeft, 'expand-to-left':expandToLeft}">

                    <ul hn-select-scroller="" scroll-lock="" ng-mouseleave="hideLargeSwatch()" ng-class="{'grid':option.isGridView}" class="whiteBackground border border-hn-secondary-lt text-small ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">

                            <div ng-show="option.selectedValue.optionValueID !== undefined" class="ng-hide">
                                <div hn-select-attr-clear="" on-option-select="clearSelected()" class="hn-select-attr-clear standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt hover-active ng-isolate-scope">
                                    <span class="icon-cancel" style="width: auto;"></span>
                                    &nbsp;<span class="clear-selection">Clear Selection</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <!-- ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Full</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $370.00<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $1,729.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Queen</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $390.00<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $1,749.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values -->
                    </ul>
                    <!-- ngIf: option.imgExists || !isAvailable -->
                </div>
</div></div>

            </div>

            <div hn-product-option="" ng-class="{'option-invalid': !option.valueSelected}" option="options[1]" class="ng-scope option-invalid">
                <div hn-select="" label="Configuration (9)" select-name=" - Configuration" on-collapse="getValueData(args)" class="marginTopOnly10px hn-option ng-isolate-scope" hn-input-disable="" hn-input-disable-exclude="lastSelectedOption == option" enable-on="hnProductOptions:updateComplete" disable-on="hnProductOptions:updating" content-width="654"><div class="HN-Select-Option">
<div ng-click="toggleContent()" style="height:100%;overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="standard-style text-small noWrap">
        <div class="HN-Opt-Lbl noWrap inline-block ng-binding" hn-bind-html="displayData">Configuration (9)</div>
        <div swatch-preview="" class="inline-block swatch-preview-cont ng-scope" style="width: 0px;">
            <!-- ngRepeat: img in swatches.images -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="HN-Item-Opt-Ar bg-hn-background icon-down-open"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-error text-small ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="hasCustomErrorCondition ? errorCondition() : (data.isCustomKitOption ? (dirty &amp;&amp; !data.valid &amp;&amp; !data.isPristine) : displayError)">
    Please Select<br>
    Your  - Configuration
</div>
<div ng-transclude="" class="hn-select-content" ng-class="{'open-to-left':openToLeft, 'expand-to-left':expandToLeft}">

                    <ul hn-select-scroller="" scroll-lock="" ng-mouseleave="hideLargeSwatch()" ng-class="{'grid':option.isGridView}" class="whiteBackground border border-hn-secondary-lt text-small ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">

                            <div ng-show="option.selectedValue.optionValueID !== undefined" class="ng-hide">
                                <div hn-select-attr-clear="" on-option-select="clearSelected()" class="hn-select-attr-clear standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt hover-active ng-isolate-scope">
                                    <span class="icon-cancel" style="width: auto;"></span>
                                    &nbsp;<span class="clear-selection">Clear Selection</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <!-- ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed Only</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $370.00<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $390.00</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + Nightstand</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $569.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $589.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + 2 Nightstands</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $759.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $779.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + Dresser + MIrror</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $869.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $889.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + Chest</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $829.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $849.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + Nightstand + Dresser + Mirror</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $1,069.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $1,089.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + Nightstand + Chest</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $1,029.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $1,049.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + Nightstand + Dresser + Mirror + Chest</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $1,529.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $1,549.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values --><li hn-product-option-value="" item="optionData" ng-repeat="optionData in option.values" ng-class="{grid:option.isGridView}" class="ng-scope">
                            <div hn-select-attr="" option="item" on-option-select="selectValue()" on-hover="getValueData(args)" grid="option.isGridView" ng-class="{'borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt':(!option.isGridView), grid:(option.isGridView)}" class="ng-isolate-scope hover-active borderBottom border-hn-secondary-lt"><div lazy-load-html="getTemplate()"><div ng-click="selectThis($event)" class="standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel':optionData.data.selectedFlag,'opt-deactive':!optionData.data.availableFlag, 'touch-hover':onHover().thisValue ==optionData.value}">
<!-- ngIf: option.optionImgExists && !option.swatchImgExists -->
<!-- ngIf: option.swatchImgExists -->
<span class="text-small HN-Item-Opt-Name ng-binding" hn-bind-html="optionData.data.text || optionData.data.name" hn-bind-html-filter="boolToCF">Bed + 2 Nightstands + Dresser + Mirror + Chest</span><br>
<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku --><span ng-if="optionData.data.availableFlag &amp;&amp; option.isPriceRangeSku" class="text-tiny text-hn-red ng-scope">
    <span ng-switch="option.isCustomKitOption">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  --><span ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
            $1,729.99<!-- ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice --><span ng-if="optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice" class="ng-scope ng-binding"> - $1,749.99</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.minDisplayPrice !== optionData.data.maxDisplayPrice -->
        </span>
    </span>
</span><!-- end ngIf: optionData.data.availableFlag && option.isPriceRangeSku -->
<!-- ngIf: !optionData.data.availableFlag -->
</div></div></div>
                        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: optionData in option.values -->
                    </ul>
                    <!-- ngIf: option.imgExists || !isAvailable -->
                </div>
</div></div>

            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the page?

Comment: How much of the HTML do you need? The entire huge chunk?

Comment: Enough that we can reproduce the problem. The idea is that you want to eliminate (or at least reduce) random guessing of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line:

```
@browser.div(:class, 'standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope').when_present.click
```

This is waiting for the first occurence of this div in the HTML to appear. In other words, it is always waiting for the "Full" bed option to appear. This works when updating the bed type, but will never appear when updating the configuration type.

You will need to scope the checking for the applicable items. There are a number of ways to do this. However, the approach requiring the minimal amount of changes is likely using the div with class "hn-select-content". It appears to exist once per dropdown.

```
numOfOptions.times do |n|
  @browser.spans(:class, 'HN-Item-Opt-Ar bg-hn-background icon-down-open')[n].when_present.click

  if @browser.div(:class, 'standard-style HN-Item-Opt relativePosition ng-scope').exists?
    @browser.div(:class, 'standard-style HN-Item-Opt relativePosition ng-scope').when_present.click
  else
    list = @browser.div(:class => 'hn-select-content', :index => n)
    list.div(:class, 'standard-style padding10px HN-Item-Opt clearfix ng-scope').when_present.click
  end
end
```